# slow vim scrolling in large file

Tags: vim

My vim starts getting low responsive when the code exceeds 150~ lines. i ran a syntime report, this is what i have, i'm not sure where cCppString comes from.

```
 2.996034   71049  0       0.001001    0.000042  cCppString         \(L\|u\|u8\|U\|R\|LR\|u8R\|uR\|UR\)\="
 2.936729   71049  0       0.002005    0.000041  cString            \(L\|u\|u8\|U\|R\|LR\|u8R\|uR\|UR\)\="
 1.575043   71049  0       0.000477    0.000022  cppRawString       \%(u8\|[uLU]\)\=R"\z([[:alnum:]_{}[\]#<>%:;.?*\+\-/\^&|~!=,"']\{,16}\)(
 1.077835   71049  0       0.000461    0.000015  cString            \%(U\|u8\=\)"
```

I only have vundle and youcompleteme plugins. Need a little help to optimize it

Edit: Problem found. Apparently turning on relative line number causes low responsiveness when scrolling.

Comment: You can run vim without your plugins like `vim -U NONE -N yourFileName.extension`

Comment: not fixed, it's not the plugins i assume

Comment: Are you using syntax highlighting? Is your cursorline set? Which vim are you running and on what system? how are the specs of the computer you are using?

My first recommendation is to put `set nocursorline` and `syntax off` in your ~/.vimrc and see if that doesn't help.